# Using multiple authentication schemes in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-core, basic-authentication, bearer-token

I have Web API developed using ASP.NET Core and I need to be able to use both Basic and Bearer authentication schemes for the same service.
For some reason it does not work: it always considers the call as a bearer one.
Here's my code:

This are the attributes I have in the controller:

```
[Authorize(ActiveAuthenticationSchemes = "Basic,Bearer")]
[ResponseCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0, VaryByHeader = "Authorization")]
```

This is my startup.cs:

this part is for basic auth:

```
   app.UseBasicAuthentication(new BasicAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AutomaticAuthenticate = false,
            AutomaticChallenge = false,
            Realm = "test",
            Events = new BasicAuthenticationEvents
            {
                OnValidateCredentials = context =>
                {
                    if (svc.IsValidCredential(context.Username, context.Password))
                    {
                        var claims = new[]
                        {
                        new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, context.Username),
                        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, context.Username)
                        };

                        context.Ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(
                            new ClaimsPrincipal(
                                new ClaimsIdentity(claims, context.Options.AuthenticationScheme)),
                            new AuthenticationProperties(),
                            context.Options.AuthenticationScheme);
                    }

                    return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
                }
            }
        });
```

And this piece of code for Bearer authentication:

```
    app.UseAPIKeyAuthentication(new BearerApiKeyOptions
        {
            AuthenticationScheme = BearerApiKeySchema,
            AutomaticAuthenticate = false  
        });
```

Comment: No reply so far. Nobody knows how to use multiple authentication?

Answer (score 5):

You may look at [this](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/issues/1062) for some reference from official Microsoft GitHub.

My use-case is slightly different, I need a combination of Cookie and Windows Authentication. You will need to use the PolicyBuilder to enforce the 'require authentication' part.

On ConfigureServices method:

```
            // add additional authorisation for cookie
            services.AddAuthorization(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("CookiePolicy", policy =>
                {
                    policy.AddAuthenticationSchemes("NTLM", "MyCookie"); // order does matter. The last scheme specified here WILL become the default Identity when accessed from User.Identity
                    policy.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
                });
            });
```

On Configure method:

```
            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions()
            {
                AuthenticationScheme = "MyCookie",
                LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login/"),
                AccessDeniedPath = new PathString("/Account/AccessDenied/"),
                AutomaticAuthenticate = false, // this will be handled by the authorisation policy
                AutomaticChallenge = false // this will be handled by the authorisation policy
            });
```

On Controller:

```
        [Authorize("CookiePolicy")] // will check policy with the required authentication scheme (cookie in this case)
        public IActionResult AuthorisedPageCookie()
        {
            return View();
        }
```